# Partial derivate of scalar-valued function of a vector variable

Tags: vector-analysis, machine-learning

Working through [Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://mml-book.github.io/) and got stuck on  the end-of-chapter exercises 5.8a):

Calculating $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ for
$$g(y) = y^T S^{-1} y$$
with $y \in \mathbb R^{D}$ and $ S \in \mathbb R^{D×D}$

My solution (which is equal to this other one I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ilmoi/MML-Book/blob/master/end%20of%20chapter%20exercises/Chapter%205%20Exercises%20-%20PDF.pdf)): $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = y^T (S^{-1} + ({S^{-1}})^T)$$ differs from the 'official' one: $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 2 y^T S^{-1}$$
Which solution is wrong? Or am I missing that both these solutions are equivalent?

Comment: Yours is correct and if S is symmetric so is theirs

Comment: Thought the same, but that’s not mentioned in the question….

Comment: If a vector an its transpose straddle a Matrix, it's typically diagonal and therefor symmetric. There could be other subtle indicators in the context.

Comment: I didn't come across such indicators; what threw me off a little bit was using the inverse of S, but I guess that's just some obfuscation. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Interpret $g$ as a ${\tt1}\times{\tt1}$ matrix. Now calculate its transpose. What are the implications?

Comment: @greg I didn't get that. The sum of S-1 and its transpose is always symmetric, but that doesn't indicate anything regarding S itself, does it?